# CFdocument losing CSS for border-bottom

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-10

When using CFdocument to create a pdf in CF10 I lose a lot of css. Is there any documentation anywhere that shows what css is allowed to be used for CFdocument or is it just keep trying and its hit or miss. Right now I am just trying to add a border-bottom style and it will not show whether its inline or a cascading style sheet.

Does anyone know where I can find what CSS can be used for CFdocument to help me make this border-bottom appear and other CSS that is not showing.

```
<cfdocument format="pdf" scale="75" backgroundvisible="yes" overwrite="no" fontembed="yes">
<tr style="border-bottom: solid 1px coral;">
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's right there with the documentation under Supported CSS Styles - [cfdocument](https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/cfml-reference/coldfusion-tags/tags-d-e/cfdocument.html)
I don't think the supported tags has changed since ColdFusion 9.

> Supported CSS styles
>
> The cfdocument tag supports the following CSS styles:
>
> background
>
> background-attachment
>
> background-color
>
> background-image
>
> background-position
>
> background-repeat
>
> border
>
> border-bottom
>
> border-bottom-color
>
> border-bottom-style (solid border only)
>
> border-bottom-width
>
> border-color
>
> border-left
>
> border-left-color
>
> border-left-style (solid border only)
>
> border-left-width
>
> border-right
>
> border-right-color
>
> border-right-style (solid border only)
>
> border-right-width
>
> border-spacing
>
> border-style (solid border only)
>
> border-top
>
> border-top-color
>
> border-top-style (solid border only)
>
> border-top-width
>
> border-width
>
> bottom
>
> clear
>
> clip
>
> color
>
> content (strings, counters only)
>
> counter-increment
>
> counter-reset
>
> cursor
>
> display
>
> float
>
> font
>
> font-family
>
> font-size
>
> font-style
>
> font-weight
>
> height
>
> left
>
> letter-spacing
>
> line-height
>
> list-style-type
>
> margin
>
> margin-bottom
>
> margin-left
>
> margin-right
>
> margin-top
>
> outline
>
> outline-color
>
> outline-style (solid, dotted, dashed only)
>
> outline-width
>
> padding
>
> padding-bottom
>
> padding-left
>
> padding-right
>
> padding-top
>
> page-break-after
>
> page-break-before
>
> page-break-inside
>
> position
>
> right
>
> text-align (left, right, and center)
>
> text-decoration
>
> text-indent
>
> top
>
> unicode-bidi
>
> vertical-align
>
> visibility
>
> white space (normal, nowrap only)
>
> width
>
> z-index

Comment: hmmm why does border-bottom not work for me then? That doesnt make much sense

Comment: Not sure? Maybe because it is an inline style on a table. I'm just guessing.

Comment: `<cfdocument format="pdf" scale="75" backgroundvisible="yes" overwrite="no" fontembed="yes">

<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/form-table.css"/>`

Comment: With CF6 - 2016, we installed WKHTMLTOPDF (free) and then generate a temporary static HTML file and use CFExecute to convert it to PDF.  It generates a smaller PDF file in less time with real CCS3 & HTML5 support and it isn't single threaded. (Even on CF2016, my clients are requesting we switch their other PDF generation to use this.) https://wkhtmltopdf.org/

Comment: Using CFDocument, we've had regular solid borders appear doubled or irregular.  Sometimes content with a background color would end up visually overlapping the border.  Font support was also hit-and-miss with strange kerning occasionally happening for no known reason.  I believe CFDocument uses an old iText PDF library that's never been updated due to licensing fees.  (NOTE: WKHTMLTOPDF also supports relative positioning, webfonts, FontAwesome, SVG & image transparencies.)

Comment: @JamesMoberg can you show me how to use it properly if you happen to have any available time?

Comment: Yes. It requires installation and may install Microsoft C Runtime (a single Windows DLL), but you can copy the remaining 3 files wherever you desire. Here are some posts, sample HTML & a CFTag I published https://gamesover2600.tumblr.com/tagged/wkhtmltopdf

Comment: @JamesMoberg hey james i got it downloaded and all can you assist me in what I am trying to do if you happen to have a chance?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46897688/coldfusion-creating-reports-with-wkhtmltopdf

Answer (score 1):

**You Can Use CSS inside cfdocument like below :**

```
<cfheader name="Content-Disposition" value="inline; filename=Example.pdf">
<cfcontent type="application/pdf">
<cfdocument format="pdf" orientation="landscape">
<style>
    tr {padding-top: 5px}
    td {font-size: 8px; padding-top: 2px}
</style>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            Example
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this issue by using a class on the tr like so.

```
tr.border_bottom td {
  border-bottom:1pt solid black;
}
```